# Making a vertically scrolling parent div which does not cause overflow of children

Tags: css, layout, scroll, overflow

I have something as follows:

```
<div style="float: left; height: 20px; overflow-y: scroll">
  <div>hello this is a test</div>
  <div>hello this is another test</div>
  <div>t1</div>
  <div>t2</div>
  <div>t3</div>
</div>
```

The parent div grows to the appropriate width to fit the largest child (which is what I want).  However, the vertical scrollbar causes the inner width to be smaller, which causes the largest child to wrap.

Is there a way to get the parent to grow to the width of the largest child + the width of the scroll bar? I've tried every margin trick I know, but nothing.

Comment: Your example works fine for me (IE8, FF3.5.9) - no wrapping occurs, although in FF I needed to increase the height to 40px to be able to see and use the scrollbar.

Comment: Yes sorry, the sample works better if it's a little taller to see the scroll bar.
I have IE8 and chrome, and what I see is that the 2nd child has the word "test" overflow to the next line (instead of being on one line).

Answer (score 0):

Found one solution, but open to any other suggestions.

By adding a right-float child to the longest child (or, if unsure which is the longest child, to every element):

```
<style type="text/css">
.stretcher { float: right; right: -50px; width: 50px; height: 1px; }
</style>

<div style="float: left; height: 20px; overflow-y: scroll">
  <div>hello this is a test</div>
  <div>hello this is another test<div class="stretcher"></div></div>
  <div>t1</div>
  <div>t2</div>
  <div>t3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some **horizontal padding** is sufficient in my tests with IE6/7

```
<div style="float: left; height: 50px; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 0 50px 0 4px;">
  <div>hello this is a test</div>
  <div>hello this is another test lorem ipsum</div>
  <div>t1</div>
  <div>t2</div>
  <div>t3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Padding does work with IE and Firefox, but not Chrome and Safari.  Thanks for the tip, though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue earlier but I dont think its possible to increase the size of an element dynamically using CSS.
But what you can try is adjusting the height dynamically using Javascript.

In jQuery you can use height() method everytime you add or remove a child element to the parent.

I did this in one of my projects but it still had issues with Opera (IE was fine ;) ). But since we don't have many clients using Opera, I ignored the issue.

FYI: I just skimmed thru your question. Please correct me if I didn't understand your problem properly

Comment: Hi Ashit, my problem was actually horizontal, not vertical.  I want the parent element to stretch horizontally to fit all children without wrapping them, and to show a vertical scrollbar if there are to many children.